# Can I edit Boolean Array Custom Property's booleans' names?

Tags: custom-properties

I want to put names on these booleans (like "Default" is the first one) but I can't seem to find how to do it.

[image: I want to put names on these booleans (like "Default" is the first one) but I can't seem to find how to do it.]